# ng-repeat with options doesn't return object as value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have a loop "ng-repeat" inside of

```
<select ng-model="something"></select>
```

so that each option in a list is rendered as an

```
<option>
```

inside of select block. My aim is to make "something" (which is a ng-model attached to select) to be equal to a selected object inside of the list. At this moment when I do "value="{{option}}" as a parameter of option, I have a JSON object as a String. But what I need is to get an object as an object. The code looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="something">
    <option ng-repeat="option in list" value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The thing I want is easily done by using ng-options, but I need to add additional "style" parameters depending on option.anotherField to each

```
<option>
```

Comment: what is structure of list object?

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar, it has an integer "id", a boolean "removed", two objects inside that contain strings, a "name" which is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-value` instead of value, which gives you the object you want:

```
<select ng-model="something">
    <option ng-repeat="option in list" ng-value="option">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you post the json? or a plunkr?

Comment: @Yaser thanks for the great tip. But one comment, I am trying to do that same, but does checking out will change the value of option list of not? in my case, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What about approach via `temp` proxy and it's relation with `something` variable with the help of `ng-change`(`$scope.setModel`) directive:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{name:'Tom',age:23},{name:'Max',age:33},{name:'Sam',age:43}];
    $scope.something = $scope.list[0];
    $scope.temp = $scope.something.name;    

    $scope.setModel = function(){
      for(var item of $scope.list)
        if(item.name == $scope.temp){
          $scope.something = item;
          break;
        }          
    }    
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <select ng-change='setModel()' ng-model='temp'>
      <option ng-repeat='option in list track by option.name' ng-attr-title='{{option.age}}'>{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div>something: {{something | json}}</div>
  </div>
```